# Increment/Decrement Counter for 3 Buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have three buttons like this on my site:

[image]

I'm trying to increment and decrement the counters but it's only working for two, the first works fine  but the second is adding 2 to every increment and the third isn't working at all.

Here is the code:

```js
$('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
  $(this).prev('input').val(val + 1);
  console.log(val);
});
$('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
  if (val !== 0) {
    $(this).next('input').val(val - 1);
  }
  if (val == 0) {
    $(this).next('input').val(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="quantitiy" for="Quantity-collection-template-new"></label>
<input class="minus minus1" type="button" value="-">
<input type="number" id="Quantity-collection-template-new" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input qty" pattern="[0-9]*" data-quantity-input="">
<input class="plus plus1" type="button" value="+">


<label class="quantitiy" for="Quantity-collection-template-new"></label>
<input class="minus minus2" type="button" value="-">
<input type="number" id="Quantity-collection-template-new" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input qty" pattern="[0-9]*" data-quantity-input="">
<input class="plus plus2" type="button" value="+">

<label class="quantitiy" for="Quantity-collection-template-new"></label>
<input class="minus minus3" type="button" value="-">
<input type="number" id="Quantity-collection-template-new" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input qty" pattern="[0-9]*" data-quantity-input="">
<input class="plus plus3" type="button" value="+">
```

Comment: your code is working fine. besides for when you press minus and it's 0 it increments to 1

Comment: I've made your code runnable. As you can see, it works as expected. What's the issue?

Comment: Ok, sorry and thank you. I thought that was the issue.

Comment: Just saying; you should try to be less aggressive when helping people, if his question is not clear enough or if you think more information is needed, you could ask for details instead of being rude.

But, I compared with the one on the website, there's one small difference. The code you provided is using `.plus` and `.minus` as identifier, website is using `.plus1` and `.plus2` and there's no `.plus3`. so, check the identifiers and try again. If you could add the code from the website here so we can see it as future reference is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to answer this here.

You're using `.plus1` and `.plus2` but there's no `.plus3` bindings on the website. Which is different from what you posted here, that's why is working, so, my advice is:

Just remove the duplicate and use the same logic here, try it again and let us know.

```
  $('.plus').on('click', function(e) { // omitted  });
  $('.minus').on('click', function(e) { // omitted });
```

This is what you have right now on the website:

```
$('.plus1').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
    $(this).prev('input').val(val + 1);
});
$('.minus1').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    if (val !== 0) {
        $(this).next('input').val(val - 1);
    }
    if (val == 0) {
        $(this).next('input').val(1);
    }
});
```

And another section;

```
$('.plus2').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
    $(this).prev('input').val(val + 1);
});
$('.minus2').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
    if (val !== 0) {
        $(this).next('input').val(val - 1);
    }
    if (val == 0) {
        $(this).next('input').val(1);
    }
});
```

A couple of suggestions;

Don't use the same id, create some logic to add at least an index for each id if they represent more or less the same thing. `product-1` and `product-2` and so on. Same Id is recipe for disaster and a no-no from the start.

Remember to update both `id` and `for` properties with unique identifiers.

`minus/plus - index` works.

Comment: Thank you! It was actually originally `.plus` and `.minus` but the increment buttons had the same problem. I'm not sure why? Shopify has annoying caching issues so I can't see the changes myself yet. If you see the `plus2` version shouldn't it work for that? It still is adding 2 every time ... ?